# Why doesn't the cut command work for a "docker image ls" command?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to get the docker image id for a certain image so I do

```
$ docker image ls

REPOSITORY                                                          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-name1             60                  4a625fb9a2a4        5 hours ago         3.97GB
987654321012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some-other-name2       365                 59b27e46effc        6 days ago          3.98GB
```

I expect this to give me the image id, i.e., 4a625fb9a2a4 in this case...

```
$ docker image ls | grep name1 | cut -d " " -f3
```

...but it doesn't, it gives a blank. What am I missing?

This NEEDS to be a simple shell script so I can embed it in a Groovy script in a Jenkinsfile pipeline.

Comment: When you specify the delimiter like that, each space counts as a separate field separator.  Use `awk` instead of the `grep | cut` combo: `awk '/name1/ { print $2}'`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because you have several " " between each data.

Easier way is to strip whitespaces to a single space and cut:

```
docker image ls | grep name1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d " " -f 3
```

---

**EDIT:** 
[chepner's answer is to prefere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50626142/7200715), *but I let this one live since original question was "why"*.

Comment: The "tr" IS what I was missing! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The best thing to do is let `docker images ls` do all the work, instead of parsing its default output.

```
$ docker image ls --filter "reference=*name1*" -q
4a625fb9a2a4
```

`--filter` replaces your `grep` command, and `-q` replaces `cut`. There is also a `--format` option for more precise control over the output, but `-q` is effectively just a shortcut for `--format '{{.ID}}'`.

If, for whatever reason, `--filter` doesn't do what you need, you can always use `--format` to produce output that is more easily parsed by other commands.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `awk` is better for splitting up columnar output.  For example:

```
$ docker image ls | awk '/fedora/ {print $3}'
cc510acfcd70
5292e27c6dac
422dc563ca32
```

Alternately, you could reform the output using `--format` to work better with `cut`:

```
$ docker image ls --format '{{ .Repository }} {{ .ID }}' | grep fedora | cut -d" " -f2
cc510acfcd70
5292e27c6dac
422dc563ca32
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "sed" command to transform the output from "docker image ls", replacing set of spaces by an unused char that you can use later with "cut" command to get the field of your interest. For example:

```
$ docker image ls | sed "s/  */#/g" | cut -f 3 -d "#"
```

In above example, you replace set of spaces by the '#' character, and then use the "cut" command to print the expected field numbered with -f.